# changing groupName at onChildClickListener, ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I have a single group in `ExpandableListView` containing 2 children, I want to set group name for the name of child clicked.

How can I get access to `TextView` that is generated in `getGroupView()` method?

By the way I will gladly hear some tips about code if can be written in better manner

```
CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

    expandableListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        }
    });
    expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int group, int position, long id) {

            String tekst = (String) parent.getExpandableListAdapter().getChild(group,position);
            parent.collapseGroup(group);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), tekst ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
 });
```

`CustomAdapter.class:`

```
private Context context;
public CustomAdapter(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
}

private String[] grupa = {"Płeć"};
private String[][] dzieci = {{"Kobieta","Mężczyzna"}};

//region gettersFolded
@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return grupa.length;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int position) {
    return dzieci[position].length;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return grupa[groupPosition];
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int group, int position) {
    return dzieci[group][position];
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int group) {
    return group;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int group, int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setText(grupa[groupPosition]);
    textView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
    textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btm_line_shape);
    textView.setTextSize(14);
    return textView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isExpanded, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setText(dzieci[groupPosition][childPosition]);
    textView.setTextSize(12);
    textView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
    return textView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
    return true;
}
//endregion Region
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: Don't put your data in your Adapter. It belongs to the Activity with your expandableListView or in the string.xml

2: To refresh your expandableListView set a new adapter with the refreshed data to your ListView.

Your Activity:

```
grupa = "Płeć";                             //declare as String
dzieci = {"Kobieta","Mężczyzna"};           //declare as String[]
customAdapter = new CustomAdapter (this, grupa, dzieci);
expandableListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int group, int position, long id) {

        String tekst = (String) parent.getExpandableListAdapter().getChild(group,position);
        parent.collapseGroup(group);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), tekst ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        grupa = dzieci[position];
        customAdapter = new CustomAdapter (yourApplication.this, grupa, dzieci);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Your Adapter:

```
private Context context;
private String grupa;
private String[] dzieci;
public CustomAdapter(Context context, String groupNames, String[] childNames)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.grupa = groupNames;
    this.dzieci = childNames;
}

//region gettersFolded
@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int position) {
    return dzieci.length;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return grupa;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int group, int position) {
    return dzieci[position];
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int group) {
    return group;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int group, int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setText(grupa);
    textView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
    textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btm_line_shape);
    textView.setTextSize(14);
    return textView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isExpanded, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setText(dzieci[childPosition]);
    textView.setTextSize(12);
    textView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
    return textView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
    return true;
}
```

If you want to use multiple groups you should try HashMaps instead of multidimensional Arrays.
Maybe this Video helps:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZxZIFnJ9jE